# WSO Micro Integrator getting system date during mapping

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I want to get the system date using the Data Mapping operations, so I thought i can do that using the "properties" operation which is supposed to allow me to "uses product-specific runtime variables" as per the documentation, but I couldn't find what is theses variables anyone can guide me how to find the full list of these variables or how to get the system date in the first place?

Comment: Check out [Synapse Message Context Properties](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/references/mediators/property-reference/message-context-properties/)

Answer (score 0):

For example

```xml
<property name="date" expression='get-property("SYSTEM_DATE", "yyyyMMddHHmmss")' scope="default"/>
```

You can check more properties [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Synapse+Message+Context+Properties) as well as the `SYSTEM_DATE` property documentation.